# Excel Charts - Single point series with target line

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I am wanting to create what should be a laughably simple chart to show total sales for one month vs a target. I want the target to be a line across the entire chart with the sales as a column.

I have a very basic table that only has 3 columns; Month, Sales and Target.
There is only ever going to be one row of data (current month)

[image: Data example]

I can only seem to get the target to show as a single point above the column by setting the chart type for the "target" series as a line with markers chart type.

How can I have this value as a target line that drawers across the entire chart?

I want this to be based on data and not hardcoded into the chart as it will change month on month.

Here is an example of what I can achieve, and what I want to achieve.

[image: chart Example]

Comment: I think what you're looking to achieve can only be done with more data points. Perhaps add data points of adjacent months with a the target column filled but leave sales blank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has to be more than one data point to define a line. If you set up your data table like this:

[image]

Then you can get a graph like this:

[image]

The default version of the graph includes August and October as x-axis labels, but you can get rid of those by setting the x-axis scale min and max to 9/1/17 and 9/30/17.

You can also make the column bar skinnier by increasing the gap width under Options.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish what you want without modifying your data table.

1. Create a column chart with two data series (actual and target).
2. Select your target series and change the series chart type to Scatter/XY.  Your target point should still be aligned with the column, if not, adjust your target point's x axis value until they're aligned-you can hard-code this value since you only have to align with this one column.
3. Select your Target point and add error bars.  Delete your vertical error bars.  Format your horizontal error bars so they're the width you prefer.

Now your actual and target values will update whenever you update your data table.